# getting 'service Error' in docker-compose up

Tags: docker

What does **service Error** mean? I'm getting this error message, although compose runs as expected, no detail is showed. Is there a way to get more details about this error message?

[image]

Comment: Can you share Dockerfile and `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Please show the code that generates the image file too.  I'd normally expect `docker-compose up` to print out a text-format error and not produce a PNG file; if that's what you're running, can you replace the image with the error?

Comment: I also run into the same issue even though after seeing the error, both image build and server spin-up works normally. It is unclear what could have been the error